# A query that uses a view as a relation

Tags: oracle, view

Can someone give me an example of a query that uses a view as a relation? or how can I turn this query as a view as a relation?

```
SELECT COUNT(Y.custorderID) AS NoOfOrders, x.city ||' '||
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(Y.dateorderplaced, 'DD-MON-RR'))
FROM (SELECT custorderid, custID, customerorder.dateorderplaced
      FROM CustomerOrder
      WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM
            TO_DATE(CustomerOrder.dateorderplaced, 'DD-MON-RR')) =1 AND  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM
      TO_DATE(CustomerOrder.dateorderplaced, 'DD-MON-RR')) = 2017
     )  Y
     INNER JOIN Customer x
         ON Y.custID = x.custID
GROUP BY x.city, y.dateOrderplaced
```

Comment: Extract is Oracle.  Is this tagged correctly

Comment: @P.Salmon my bad Sir

Comment: What is a "view as relation"? Note: you can simply use views as if they were tables.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes tbh I don't know but apparently its a thing

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "turn this query as a view as a relation".

Comment: The query above is a query that uses a sub query as a relation but I was thinking if you have to create a view as a relation it would also be the same thing just I would have to to create a view but apparently it don't work like that so I am confuse @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: that "subquery/view as a relation" doesn't mean anything in SQL, AFAIK. It may mean something in other places (seems to be used in Oracle's CPL, for example), but not in SQL. Perhaps you're asking if you can convert the subquery into a view? You could do that, but Oracle doesn't support parameterized views (although there are some work-arounds if you absolutely must). I'd stick with the query as is, if I were you.

Comment: I've heard of the set of data defined as Y in your query referred to as a derived table or an Inline view.  Perhaps that's what they mean?  I don't see why you would create a query this way; maybe if it was more complex or the OrderHeader info were to be "reused" I also don't see why you need to to_date what appears to be a date field.  If they aren't date fields; oi vey.

Comment: Anyone knows how to use a view in a from clause?

Comment: Like you would any table.  Create the view and reference it like you would a table.

Comment: @xQbert ok thx imma try it

Answer (score 0):

```
Create view getProducts_v as (
  SELECT * 
  FROM  Product
  WHERE Active = 'Y' and OnHandQty>0);

SELECT * 
FROM  GetProducts_v P
INNER JOIN  ProductCategory PC
 on PC.ProductID = P.ID
WHERE PC.Name in ('Houseware','Kitchen')
```

The view getProducts_v only provides a list of items that are active and which availability exists.

The query then uses the view to get a list of only those products in housewares kitchen.  Since the view already filtered out the inactive and those with 0 onHandQty, we only show users things we have instock and active.

Taking what you have:

```
CREATE view GetOrderHeader_v as (
      SELECT custorderid, custID, customerorder.dateorderplaced
      FROM CustomerOrder
     );

SELECT COUNT(gOH.custorderID) AS NoOfOrders
     , x.city ||' '||  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(gOH.dateorderplaced, 'DD-MON-RR')) 
FROM  GetOrderHeader_v gOH
INNER JOIN Customer x
   ON gOH.custID = x.custID
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(gOH.dateorderplaced, 'DD-MON-RR')) =1 
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(gOH.dateorderplaced, 'DD-MON-RR')) = 2017
GROUP BY x.city ||' '||  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(Y.dateorderplaced, 'DD-MON-RR')) 
       , gOH.dateOrderplaced;
```

Note I wouldn't use the to_date above if the field is already a date datatype as it adds unnecessary overhead.  If  dateorderplaced isn't already a date, I would have some concerns with the table structures.

Normally I would only use such a view on a complex query or if I wanted to encase a table in logic to eliminate redundant checks; such as we only ever show active products; but we do not delete products from our product table so we have the developers reference the GetProducts_v which never shows deleted products or ones that are out of stock.